# How to extract number from array of string? (I m using regex)

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a array of string

```
test= ["ChangeServer<br/>Test: 3-7<br/>PinCode:DFSFSDFB04008<br/>ShipCode:DFADFSDFSDM-000D3<br/>SomeCode:sdfsdf", "werwerwe", "adfsdfsd", 
"sdfsdfsdfsd<br/>Test: 9<br/>PinCode:ADFSDF4NS0<br/>ShipCode:FADFSDFD-9ZM170<br/>"]
```

I want to grab the number after `Test:` which in the above array of string are `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7` ( range 3-7) and `9`

**Desired output:**

```
["3","4","5","6","7","9"]
```

What I tried so far

```
test.join.scan(/(?<=Test: )[0-9]+/)
=> ["3", "7"]
```

How to deal with range?

Second test case:

```
    test= ["ChangeServer<br/>Test: 3-7<br/>PinCode:DFSFSDFB04008<br/>ShipCode:DFADFSDFSDM-000D3<br/>SomeCode:sdfsdf", "werwerwe", "adfsdfsd", 
"sdfsdfsdfsd<br/>Test: 9<br/>PinCode:ADFSDF4NS0<br/>ShipCode:FADFSDFD-9ZM170<br/>", "sdfsdfsdfsd<br/>Test: 15-18<br/>PinCode:ADFSDF4NS0<br/>ShipCode:FADFSDFD-9ZM170<br/>"]
```

Desired output:

```
["3","4","5","6","7","9","15","16","17","18"]
```

Comment: Are the numbers always single-digit?

Comment: No, i may be double or triple.

Comment: Do it step by step: **1)** extract `"3-7"` and `"9"`, **2)** Figure out how to convert `"3-7"` to `['3','4','5','6','7']`, **3)** combine the results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a new `Range` for each *range* found (i.e `N-N`) using the splat operator (i.e. `*`) and combine the results, like this <sup>1</sup>:

```
test.join.scan(/(?<=Test: )[0-9-]+/)
         .flat_map { |r| Range.new(*r.split('-').values_at(0, -1)).to_a }
#=> ["3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9"]
```

This will work for both examples.

<sup>1</sup> *Notice the the **added `-`** next to `0-9` in the regex.*

> Is the a way where we can include both `Test: 1` (with space between
>   Test: and 1) and `Test:1` (without space between Test: and 1)?

Yes, update your regex (change where *space* is placed) and add an additional `map` to get rid of those spaces:

```
test.join
    .scan(/(?<=Test:)[ 0-9-]+/)
    .map(&:strip)
    .flat_map { |r| Range.new(*r.split('-').values_at(0, -1)).to_a }
```

And here's shortened option using two captures in the regex, as [suggested by Jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44807972/how-to-extract-number-from-array-of-string-i-m-using-regex/44808165?noredirect=1#comment76602185_44808165).

```
test.join
    .scan(/Test:\s*(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?/)
    .flat_map { |m,n| (m..n||m).to_a }
```

Comment: Thank you but there is extra number `8` which shouldn't be there.

Comment: Is the a way where we can include both `Test: 1`(with space between Test: and 1)  and `Test:1` (without space between Test: and 1)?

Comment: I think you can do away with the ternary altogether.

Comment: @Kavincat Yes, adding an additional `map` to the result of `scan`, and changing the _space_ in regex. Check updated answer.

Comment: @iceツ I also thought of that, but `Range.new` need 2..3 arguments, so won't work for all cases.

Comment: `flat_map { |r| Range.new(*r.split('-').values_at(0, -1)).to_a }` would work for both, `a-b` notation and single values.

Comment: @Stefan Great, thank you! I wanted to get rid of the ternary but couldn't figure out how. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Using a capture you can get rid of `.map(&:strip)`: `.scan(/Test:\s*([ 0-9-]+)/).flat_map {|r,| ... }`. Personally, though, I'd use two captures and get rid of the whole `split('-')` thing: `test.join.scan(/Test:\s*(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?/).flat_map {|m,n| (m..n||m).to_a }`

Comment: @JordanRunning Thanks for your suggestion, i like it better than my original answer. I updated my answer, but your solution may well be posted as another answer (i'll rollback if you decide to add it).

Comment: @Gerry I'm pretty happy with my answer without `join`, so you're welcome to it.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of ways you could solve this. I'd probably do it this way:

```
test.flat_map do |s|
  _, m, n = *s.match(/Test:\s*(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?/)
  m ? (m..n||m).to_a : []
end
```

See it in action on repl.it: https://repl.it/JFwT/13

Or, more succinctly:

```
test.flat_map {|s| s.match(/Test:\s*(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?/) { $1..($2||$1) }.to_a }
```

https://repl.it/JFwT/11

Comment: Interesting and neat solution! BTW, you could get the exact desired output  (strings instead of numbers) removing `to_i`.

Comment: Since the OP wants an array of strings, you could shorten it to `m.upto(n || m).to_a`

Comment: @Gerry, Stefan: Thanks for your suggestions; I've updated my answer.

Comment: I really enjoyed this answer especially the "succinct" version. So just for fun Benchmarks available at https://repl.it/JFwT/16

Comment: @engineersmnky It was fun to write. I'm not surprised by the benchmark result. `Array#join` is pretty well-optimized.

Comment: Surprisingly well optimized to the point where it is faster than `inspect`

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity:

```
test.
  join.
  scan(/(?<=Test: )[\d-]+/).
  map { |e| e.gsub(/\A\d+\Z/) { |m| "#{m}..#{m}" }.gsub('-', '..') }.
  map(&method(:eval)).
  flat_map(&:to_a)
```